# Subclassing LoginForm

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am trying to subclass the loginform to add an extra field per login but cannot get it to display. I am using mezzanine for the project.

Here is what I have for my forms.py:

```
from mezzanine.accounts.forms import LoginForm
from django import forms


CLINICS = (
('', '——–'),
('1', 'Main'),
('2', 'Secondary'),
('3', 'Backend'),
       )


class myLoginForm(LoginForm):
    clinic_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CLINICS)
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import (authenticate, login as auth_login,
                                           logout as auth_logout)
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.messages import info, error
from django.core.urlresolvers import NoReverseMatch
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from accounts.forms import myLoginForm
from mezzanine.utils.urls import login_redirect


def login(request, template="templates/accounts/account_login.html"):
    """
    Login form.
    """
    form = myLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        authenticated_user = form.save()
        info(request, _("Successfully logged in"))
        auth_login(request, authenticated_user)
        return login_redirect(request)
    context = {"form": form, "title": _("CaregoLite Log In")}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And this is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.core.views import direct_to_template
from django.views.generic.base import View

url("^$", "accounts.views.login", name="home"),
#url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
```

For whatever reason though I cannot get this subclassed form to show. In my debug I can see that the only request var done is for mezzanine.accounts.views.login.

Does anything look out of whack in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check how does the template outputs the form? Maybe it does field by field instead of a loop or `as_p`.

Comment: It does this:    {% block main %}
    <fieldset>
    <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
    <form method="post"{% if form.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
    {% fields_for form %}
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="{{ title }}">
    </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
{% endblock %}

Comment: @tbonejo Looks like mezzanine uses its own [`mezzanine.forms`](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/packages.html#module-mezzanine.forms) package instead of Django's `django.forms`, so you may have to use a different method to add new fields to the default forms.

Comment: unfortunately mezzanine.forms does not include choicefield:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example above, which is very different at this point from what we have been discussing outside of SO, your url pattern is calling "accounts.views.login". It should probably be appname.views.login, or views.login, if your views.py is in the root of your project.